# C# Linq Join not equal

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a linq join for a game that will select all the positions a player does not play in using the following query:

```
var m_player_positions = from pl in tfs.Players
                         join pos in tfs.Positions
                             on new { X = true } equals new { X = (pl.MainPositionID != pos.PositionID) }
                         select new {PlayerName = pl.Forename, Position = pos.Name};
```

i am aware now that i am unable to use pl within the right hand side of the join equals, and cannot use pos within the left hand side, is there a way to perform this particular join with linq?

Comment: sorry, just made the edit, it was supposed to be `pl.MainPositionID != pos.PositionID`

Comment: I believe you are looking for a left outer join. See this stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434313/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: This links gives a very good explanation of joins and should illustrate why a left outer join will fulfill your needs http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Just a quick comment. Using Linq in a game may not be a good idea. While the programming model is really nice and it may even offer a performance boost in some cases, in games you may often see the opposite. Running a Linq query will create many temporary objects and this may cause garbage collections and these may again cause your game to "stutter". So you should at least avoid Linq inside your game loop.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad What would you suggest instead? We can only assume that LINQ interpretations are as lean as possible.

Comment: @Gudsor I suggest that we avoid Linq in loops where timing is critical, like in a game loop. Instead we should use old-fashioned for-loops and avoid object creations as much as possible.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad arguably, Linq queries are 'create once, use many' but it does require design over head that a `foreach` would avoid. Is left outer join actually faster without linq? I would love to see a perf sample.

Answer (score 3):

You basically can do this using `SelectMany`:

```
var m_player_positions =
    tfs.Players.SelectMany(
                    pl => tfs.Positions
                             .Where(pos => pl.MainPositionID != pos.PositionID)
                             .Select(pos => new {PlayerName = pl.Forename, Position = pos.Name}));
```

Answer (score 2):

I was beaten to it, but here you go.

```
  var m_player_positions = from pl in tfs.Players
                         join pos in tfs.Positions
                             on pl.MainPositionID == pos.PositionID
                         select new {PlayerName = pl.Forename, Position = pos.Name};
```

The restrictions on 'equals' were chosen to ensure that only equalities are used in joins.This is because queries with more advanced logic cannot translate reliably into relational statements.

Consider the 2nd paragraph of this documentation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: sorry, edited the question, was supposed to be `pl.MainPositionID != pos.PositionID`

Comment: Not sure i like being voted down because the goalposts moved. Feels too much like work for my liking :D